# Service layer automation using Fitnesse

Tags: automated-testing, fitnesse

Does anybody used Fitnesse before? I am new to Fitnesse trying to set the automation framework at the Service layer. Any idea of how to do it in Fitnesse and any resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hai me also new to the fitnesse .... i to have the same problem please help me if u got the solution

Answer (score 2):

When you say service layer what exactly do you mean?

Fitnesse is composed of two components - Fitnesse tables and the fixtures.
So you should be able to test any system at which ever layer you want.

Back end service layer testing(Example: webservice testing, database testing)
Front end testing - There are a few Fitnesse projects to do it - Selenesse , Xebium

We do a lot of webservice testing and database testing using Fitnesse

Fitnesse pages for webservice testing - using script and decision table
Database testing - using Query table.

Using SLIM for Fitnesse and the fixtures were written in C#

Comment: I would just clarify better why fixtures matters here. A fixture is "glue" between your actual test (or test driver) and the system under test. So it translates a request from your test to the system and then a response from the system back to the test. So depending on the type of system... for Web Service it may create and send SOAP requests, and parse SOAP responses. It may write a message to the queue or read it from there.

Comment: If there are libraries for creating frontend fixtures like Selenesse/Xebium, are there similar libraries for backend, e.g. to create and send a SOAP request directly from Fitnesse? There are tons of frameworks for creating and manipulating XML, evaluating XPath exprs, and creating Web service client stubs, but I wonder if there is one well integrated with Fitnesse. I mean SOAP UI for Fitnesse.

Comment: The last commit for Selenesse was on Nov 17, 2010. Is Xebium more alive?